# Convert WBXML to XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, wbxml

How can I convert WBXML (WAP Binary XML) data to XML in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching Google with [java convert wbxml to xml](https://www.google.ca/search?q=java+convert+wbxml+to+xml&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=nhP3U4b_BsnY8gfZzIHIAw) you find [Creating & Parsing WBXML with Java using kXML 2](http://www.virtualzone.de/2011/02/creating-parsing-wbxml-with-java-using.html).